# Ubuntu 17.10 keeps on restarting each time I connect an external monitor

Tags: intel-graphics

I have Intel GMA 950 video on my HP Mini 100-1030 that keeps on restarting (going to the login screen) each time I connect to an external monitor. My system is running Ubuntu 17.10
The monitor connects fine on my other system running Windows 10.

```
server glx version string: 1.4 client
glx version string: 1.4 
GLX version: 1.4 Max 
core profile version: 3.3 Max 
compat profile version: 3.0 Max GLES1 
profile version: 1.1 Max 
GLES[23] profile version: 3.0 OpenGL 
core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.2.2 OpenGL 
core profile shading language version string: 3.30 OpenGL 
version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.2.2 OpenGL 
shading language version string: 1.30 OpenGL ES 
profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 17.2.2 OpenGL 
ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
```

Comment: Does it actually restarts or just logs you off the current session? Quite different cases...

Comment: It just logs me off the current session.